# Sample apps of Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I want to develop a Google Glass app. I am confused on how to implement the UI. Can anyone please suggest me some tutorials on developing Google Glass. 
Also i dont have Google Glass device. I have heard the emulator is not available for Google Glass. Is there any way to test the apps without having the device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no publicly available emulator, so you need real device to test your app. Also, all things are documented here: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/

Comment: here u mentioned real device means android phones or google glass device.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can't and hope Google will publish the simulator soon. Meanwhile, you could check some of the presentation, and open source codes.

http://www.slideshare.net/getdinesh/google-glass-an-intro-v-1

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/overview

https://github.com/harrywye/gdkdemo

https://github.com/Acarin/GDGBaltimore